# Port forwarding to VPN client

Tags: debian, openvpn, port-forwarding

I ran into a problem which seems I can't solve.
I have a VPN server on a VPS. I can connect with my client PC(home lan).
It works as it should. I get the VPS IP address on the client PC.

However I would like to be able to connect through the VPN to the client PC using a specific port. I have a MineCraft server and I would like to be able to connect to MC server through the VPN.

I enabled IP forwarding:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Tried to forward the specific port:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 50.x.x.x -p tcp --dport 25565 -j DNAT --to-dest 10.98.0.2:25565
```

50.x.x.x is my VPN public IP address. 10.98.0.2 is the client's local(tun0) IP address.

For some reason its not working. `tcpdump port 25565` shows this on the VPN server when I try to connect to the client:

```
20:49:58.345498 IP MyInternetPublicIP.62336 > VPNPublicIP.25565: Flags [S], seq 2320085851, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:50:01.344059 IP MyInternetPublicIP.62336 > VPNPublicIP.25565: Flags [S], seq 2320085851, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:50:07.342439 IP MyInternetPublicIP.62336 > VPNPublicIP.25565: Flags [S], seq 2320085851, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

On the client side nothing shows up. I'm sure I'm missing something just don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to allow forwarding in the filter table (in the `FORWARD` chain or a chain called from there) with something like this:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 10.98.0.2 -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
```

Without special configuration on the client side which makes sure that the response packets are sent through the VPN you also have to configure SNAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -d 10.98.0.2 -p tcp --dport 25565 -j SNAT --to-source 10.98.0.1
```

Assuming that 10.98.0.1 is the VPS VPN address.